# GAN Training loop: should one epoch *ACTUALLY* see every image in the dataset or are repeats fine (example included)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Okay, I've always been confused on this due to the different examples online.
I know an epoch means the entire dataset has been passed through the GAN once.

But, MOST of the training loops I've seen online start like this:

```
def train_gan(generator, discriminator, dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs, n_batch):
 # calculate the number of batches per epoch
 batches_per_epoch = int(len(dataset) / n_batch)
 # calculate the number of training iterations
 n_steps = batches_per_epoch * n_epochs
 # gan training algorithm
 for i in range(n_steps):
 # generate points in the latent space
 z = randn(latent_dim * n_batch)
 # reshape into a batch of inputs for the network
 z = z.reshape(n_batch, latent_dim)
 # generate fake images
 fake = generator.predict(z)
 # select a batch of random real images
 ix = randint(0, len(dataset), n_batch) <---- *LOOK AT THIS LINE*
 # retrieve real images
 real = dataset[ix]
```

Notice the code under "#select a batch of random real images". Because of the use of "randint", the images sampled per batch are RANDOMLY selected from the ENTIRE dataset. This means images from the training dataset could be repeated per batch (e.g. images 1,2,3 are randomly chosen for the first batch, and then images 5,2,3 are randomly selected for the second batch -- 3 is repeated).

So, after one epoch, the entire dataset has NOT been seen (since repeats were included). Why do most examples do it this way? I would think you should do it this way:  1) shuffle the entire dataset before each epoch and 2) split the data into the correct # of batches for that epoch and then 3) iterate over each of these pre-split batches. This way, all the data is actually seen per epoch and there are no repeats.

Does it not matter if all the data isn't seen per epoch? What am I missing here?